# Would Linux be considerably faster on a Netbook with Intel Atom processor?

Tags: linux, netbook

I've got an EEE Netbook with Intel Atom processor and Win XP.

Probably 90% of the time I'm using it for webbrowsing and thinking of dual booting it in Linux and then booting into Windows only when I need to...if it would speed things up.

I've tried using FF and Chrome, both are about equally slow on the netbook.

Anyone have any idea of the comparative stats on this?

Comment: If you're really just looking for a more responsive browser, try Opera. Otherwise, try a netbook distro like the Ubuntu Netbook Remix, or see if you can get Arch+XFCE running on it.

Answer (score 1):

My EEE Netbook felt really sluggish until I completely wiped it and reinstalled Windows XP Pro, SP3 (it came with XP).

I spent quite a bit of time looking at services, memory usage, etc. and inexplicably, cpu would spike up to 100% on Firefox all the time, Chrome was slightly better, but overall, a really poor experience (2 GB RAM too) until I formatted/reinstalled.

I've heard really good things about Moblin and there's a LiveCD you can try that'll allow you to test drive it without making any changes:
http://moblin.org/

Comment: Where did you reinstall Windows from (since the netbook doesn't have a CD drive)? I.e., where did you "run" the Windows installer from?
Does the Bios support Flash devices or something?

Comment: I re-installed with a 2GB USB key using nLite and a few other utilities; think this was the article I used: http://www.eeeguides.com/2007/11/installing-windows-xp-from-usb-thumb.html

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu netbook boots at a really good speed. If you can configure it. I installed it to a toshiba nb305. And was really difficult to get it booting without errors. But after the errors went solved... everything loads really fast